# Is $\phi$ a groupoid monomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monomorphisms

Consider the binary algebraic structures $\langle\mathbb{R}, +\rangle$ and $\langle\mathbb{R}^{+}, \cdot\rangle$, and the mapping $\phi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ where $\phi(x) = e^{x}$. We know that $\phi$ is monomorphic since

- $f(a + b) = e^{a + b} = e^{a} \cdot e^{b} = f(a) \cdot f(b) \; \forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, and
- $f(a) = e^{a}$ and $f(b) = e^{b}$. Then $f(a) = f(b) \Rightarrow e^{a} = e^{b} \Rightarrow \ln e^{a} = \ln e^{b} \Rightarrow a = b$;

My question is, what does it mean for $\phi$ to be a **groupoid** monomorphism? How do we show this? I'm not sure of what I'm supposed to show, since $\langle\mathbb{R}, +\rangle$ and $\langle\mathbb{R}^{+}, \cdot\rangle$ are both Abelian groups?

Comment: A groupoid (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid#Category_theoretic) is a category with invertible morphisms, and any group can be naturally regarded as a groupoid with one object. A monomorphism between groupoids would probably be a functor between them which is one-to-one in some sense. What's the definition given in your context?

Comment: Whoever gave you this task I'm pretty sure he wanted to say group monomorphism.

Comment: @freakish You think?

Comment: @HewWolff Well, I'm not asking under the context of category theory, since I haven't taken such a course. But I am asking under the context of group theory. As for the definitions, let $G$ be a set and $*$ be a binary operation. Then $G$ is a groupoid if and only if the closure property of $*$ is satisfied. Also, let $f$ be a group homomorphism from $A$ to $B$. Then $f$ is a monomorphism if $f(a) = f(b) \Leftrightarrow a = b \; \forall a, b \in A$.

Comment: From the point of view of algebra, a groupoid homomorphism could be a mapping of the underlying sets which preserves both $*$ (where it's defined) and $^{-1}$. And a groupoid monomorphism could be such a mapping which is one-to-one. But without knowing the actual definitions, it's hard to say.

Comment: @HewWolff Yeah, I wasn't given a definition. But suppose the groupoid is a one-to-one mapping between the structures I defined above, won't that result in an error since the structures aren't groupoids?

Comment: Well, your structures are groups, so they are groupoids a standard way.

Comment: @Abdulrahman You say that you did not take category theory course. There's no point to introduce the notion of groupoid in group theory course. Especially when both objects in question are actually groups. So yeah, I'm pretty sure it is just a mistake, and what you already have is enough.